# YouTube API V3 keeps giving me quota exceeded error

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Been using [youtube-uploader](https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload/) for almost a year without any issues. All of a sudden I keep getting this error:

**"The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota"**

I am only uploading one video per day which is far below the 5/day limit.

When I login to console.cloud.google.com and look at the YouTube Data API v3, I see some strange stuff.

I click on Quotas and do not see anything about the 10,000 units per day. I just see:

Queries per day | 0 |
Queries per minute per user | 180,000 |
Queries per minute | 1,800,000 |

Then I see a graph of Quota exceeded errors count (3 hr) - Queries per day and I can see a few spikes over a few days. Not sure what is causing the error. I am tempted to just delete the API and create new credentials. But am hoping for some better solution than this nuclear option!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did some research and you have to submit your app for verification. Basically need to fill out all the fields on the oauth consent form, then at the end it will ask you to submit it for verification. YouTube makes this whole process very complicated and confusing. They don't realize that mom and pop businesses are not corporations that can handle all this complexity.

Comment: Verified domain and app on the OAuth consent doesn't help.

Comment: I think you also need to request "Restricted scopes" for YouTube Data api v3 or something.

Comment: No, it is just playlist with video information (length - for example). It is not restricted.